# Read cities and streets into a database without api

Tags: mysql, openstreetmap

I managed to download and extract an osm-file into a mysql-database, like:

osmosis --read-xml myfile.osm --write-apidb dbType="mysql" host="localhost" database="osm" user="osm"

What I now need is a way to get only cities and their streets into the database and query them. So how do I limit the data passed from the osm-file to the database to cities and streets? I don't need any additional data.

I do not want to use any only APIs or services.

Answer (score 0):

[Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) supports so-called [data manipulation tasks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage#Data_Manipulation_Tasks) which can be used to filter for specific data. In order to get only cities and streets it should be sufficient to filter for both the [place](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aplace) and [highway](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway) tags (nodes as well as areas). The required parameters seem to be `--tf accept-ways place=* --tf accept-nodes place=* --tf accept-ways highway=* --tf accept-nodes highway=*` but I never used osmosis myself.